# ExecuteNonQuery() won't work for INSERT function

Tags: vb.net

First of all, I'm not a professional programmer. So there are some big faults possible in my program!

The problem is:

I linked my WPF file in visual express with a MS Access database (format 2003). Whenever I try to run the following (sorry for the dutch code):

```
Public Sub ToevoegenPersoon(voornaam As String, achternaam As String, mailadres As String, geboortedatum As Date, klantennummer As Integer, specialeCategorie As String)
    Dim opdracht As OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlOpdracht As String
    sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO Klant (Voornaam, achternaam, mailadres, geboortedatum, klantennummer, specialeCategorie)" & _
          "VALUES (" & Chr(34) & "" & voornaam & "" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "" & achternaam & "" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "" & _
           mailadres & "" & Chr(34) & "," & Convert.ToString(geboortedatum) & "," & Convert.ToString(klantennummer) & "," & Chr(34) & "" & specialeCategorie & "" & Chr(34) & ")"

    opdracht = New OleDbCommand(sqlOpdracht, connectie)
Debug.WriteLine(sqlOpdracht)
MsgBox(sqlOpdracht)

opdracht.Connection.Open()
opdracht.ExecuteNonQuery()
opdracht.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

my program always has an error for the ExecuteNonQuery() function. This function is used for the following event:

```
Private Sub btnKlantToevoegen_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnKlantToevoegen.Click
    Dim achternaam As String = boxVoornaam.Text
    Dim voornaam As String = boxAchternaam.Text
    Dim emailadres As String = boxEmailadres.Text
    Dim geboortedatum As Date = GeboortedatumSelectie.SelectedDate
    Dim klantennummer As Integer = 5
    Dim specialeCategorie As String = "Jeugd"

    Try
    database.ToevoegenPersoon(voornaam, achternaam, emailadres, geboortedatum, klantennummer, specialeCategorie)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    boxAchternaam.Clear()
    boxVoornaam.Clear()
    boxEmailadres.Clear()



End Sub
```

At the top, I stated the following to connect MS Access database with Visual express:

```
Private connectiestring As String = My.Settings.Database_Drijkoningen_Konings1ConnectionString
    Private connectie As OleDbConnection
    connectie = New OleDbConnection(connectiestring)
```

When running this program, the executenonquery() gives an error. And I have no clue whatsoever what it can be. Anybody who does?

Thanks in advance

Jeroen

Comment: Can you not use a single quote instead of double quotes?

Comment: `my program always has an error `  care to share any details about that?

Comment: Could you copy error message, it could be helpful

Comment: debug and have a look at what's in sqlOpdracht, my wild guess is not exactly valid sql... Have a look a parameterised sql queries urgently, aside from being more secure, this sort of error is much less likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this could resolve your problem. I don't know the error message. However I will show a simple parameterized query that probably could help a lot

```
Public Sub ToevoegenPersoon(voornaam As String, achternaam As String, mailadres As String, geboortedatum As Date, klantennummer As Integer, specialeCategorie As String)
    Dim opdracht As OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlOpdracht As String
    sqlOpdracht = "INSERT INTO Klant (Voornaam, achternaam, mailadres, " & _ 
                  "geboortedatum, klantennummer, specialeCategorie) " & _
                  "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    opdracht = New OleDbCommand(sqlOpdracht, connectie)
    opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", voornaam)
    opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", achternaam)
    opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", mailadres)
    opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Convert.ToString(geboortedatum))
    opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Convert.ToString(klantennummer))
    opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", specialeCategorie)
    opdracht.Connection.Open()
    opdracht.ExecuteNonQuery()
    opdracht.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Now, with a parameterized query there is no more concatenations on the command text and this alone will remove any possibility to forget some quote or comma between value. (Of course this removes also the Sql Injection problem and the parsing of strings that contain special characters)

There is still a problem to be resolved. The 4th and 5th parameter receive a string value. This requires the underlying field on the datatable to be a string field and not a DateTime. If this is not the case then you need to pass (as parameter value) just the date value

Comment: I used your code, but I removed the converts (since geboortedatum is a Datetype in the database). However now I get the error that 'specialeCategorie' is a unknown fieldname in my INSERT function.

Comment: Did you check your table `Klant` if the field exists and it is named exactly `SpecialeCategorie` (upper/lower case not important)

Comment: This category 'SpecialeCategorie' is a restricted String, with 4 possibillities. These possibilities however are based upon the year of birth of the 'klant'

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. If you open the database file with Access and look at the structure of the table Klant, did you see a field named SpecialeCategorie? If yes, what datatype is it?

Comment: Yes I see a column named SpecialeCategorie. It contains a string, however, there are only four options to fill it(Jeugd-senior-student-regulier)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any reason for your error message. If you are willing to share an empty copy of the database I can try to produce a little test with LinqPAD to see if there are other hidden problems not clear from the code above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the answer you gave us was already helpful. Together with a friend however I figured out the mistake and fixed it! So thank you for the help :)

Comment: Then I suggest you to post your own answer where you explain how you managed to resolve the problem. In this way your question (and your answer) will be useful to future readers.

Comment: The column 'SpecialeCategorie' was a restricted String, which only allowed 4 possible words in this category. Although one of these words were used to fill it in the test, it still gave an error. By changing this restricted string to a normal string in the MS Access database fixed the problem.